# Confusing on an integral involving $(-\Delta)^{m}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading a paper on some class of evolution equations. I have a problem with the following integration:
$$
\int_{\Omega}|v|^{r-2}v\ (-\Delta)^{m}v\ dx=(r-1)^{m}\int_{\Omega}|v|^{r-2}|D^{m}v|^{2}\ dx, \tag  1 
$$ 
where
$\Omega\subset R^{n}$, is open bdd and $2<r<\frac{2m}{n-2m}$ for $n>2m$ with 
$$
\frac{\partial^{i}v}{\partial\nu^{i}}=0,\quad for\quad i=0,1,\dots,m-1,\quad x\in\partial \Omega. 
$$
I recall that $D^{m}=\nabla .\nabla\dots\nabla$ and $D^{2m}=(\Delta)^{m}$. I'm confusing that how we can obtain the above integral by using Green's formula repeatedly. I think that above identity is true only for $m=1$. Since
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\Omega}|v|^{r-2}v\ (-\Delta)^{m}v\ dx&=(-1)^{m+1}\int_{\Omega}D(|v|^{r-2}v)D^{2m-1}vdx\\&=(-1)^{m+2}\int_{\Omega}D^{2}(|v|^{r-2}v)D^{2m-2}vdx=\cdots=\int_{\Omega}D^{m}(|v|^{r-2}v)D^{m}vdx,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and this is not equal to the right hand side of (1). Am I right? If so, how I can derive an expression for $D^{m}(|v|^{q}v)$?

Comment: $D^m$ definition is not clear

Comment: D denotes the gradient operator, that is $Du=\nabla u= (u_{x_{1}},\ldots,u_{x_{n}})$.

Comment: So $D^m u$ is an $\underbrace{n \times n \times \dots \times n}_{m \text{ times}}$ tensor?

Comment: No, In fact we have a pde with solutions on $H_{0}^{m}(\Omega)$. More precisely, $D^{m}u=\Delta^{s}u$  if $m=2s$ and  $D^{m}u=D\Delta^{s}u$ if   $m=2s+1$.

Comment: Could you give references for the paper?

Comment: yes, just a minute.

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.2478/s11533-010-0096-2,  page 689, line 11.